# Access on SQL reporting server for Report in report builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have developed a report in report builder and published it to SQL server reporting services.  I can see the report in the 'Paginated reports' and also run it.  I've granted edit rights access to the clients (tmbodo and inaseya) on Security in the reporting service - see image.  But it says the client does not have access.  Where else should I grant access for them to be able to access and run the report?[image]

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting and at what point? There are various things that can prevent a report from running but we will need more info.

Comment: When the employee clicks on the report, it displays the following error: An error has occurred during report processing (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot create a connection to data source <name of data source'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Comment: It's not the report this is directly the problem. The problem is with the datasource. If the datasource uses windows login for example, you need to make sure that user has access to the database(s) that the datasource accesses. You might need to set the datasource to use fixed credentials, at least whilst you test.

Comment: Thank you Alan for your help, you were right.  It turns out that the user I use to connect via Report Builder to the database only has Windows Auth access - I have to request from the sys admin to grant the user Windows and SQL credential rights.